# what do we say "English Department" or "Department of English"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I would like to know whether these phrases "English Department" and "Department of English" have the same meaning. Is the term "English department" refers to "a department in England" or something else, and whether "Department of English" means the academic place where English is taught? Thanks!

Comment: You have recently asked the same question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!